# Docker SDK for Python: how to build an image with custom Dockerfile AND custom context

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to replicate this command with the Docker SDK for Python:

```
docker build -f path/to/dockerfile/Dockerfile.name -t image:version path/to/context/.
```

**path/to/dockerfile** and **path/to/context** are different paths, ie:
**/opt/project/dockerfile** and **/opt/project/src/app/.**

The directory structure is the following:

```
opt
├── project
│   ├── dockerfile
│   │   └── Dockerfile.name
│   └── src
│       └── app
│           └── target
│               └── app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
└── script.py
```

The command is working correctly from the CLI, but I'm not able to make it work with the SDK.

From [the documentation](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), the images build method has the following parameters:

- **path (str) – Path to the directory containing the Dockerfile** (I'm guessing this is the context)
- **custom_context (bool) – Optional if using fileobj**
- **fileobj – A file object to use as the Dockerfile. (Or a file-like object)**

When I use the method like this:

```
client.images.build(
    path = path_to_context,
    fileobj=open(path_to_file, 'rb'),
    custom_context=True,
    tag='image:version'
)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 33, in <module>
    client.images.build(
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/docker/models/images.py", line 298, in build
    raise BuildError(last_event or 'Unknown', result_stream)
docker.errors.BuildError: {'message': 'unexpected EOF'}
```

The content of the Dockerfile is the following:

```
FROM openjdk:16-alpine
COPY target/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "-Dspring.profiles.active=docker", "/app.jar"]
```

but I'm guessing the error is not due to that for the command correctly works with the CLI, it's only breaking with the SDK.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Edit:

Simply removing **custom_context=True** does not solve the problem, for the context and build paths are different. In fact it causes another error, relative to the fact that the file does not exist in the current path:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 33, in <module>
    client.images.build(
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/docker/models/images.py", line 287, in build
    raise BuildError(chunk['error'], result_stream)
docker.errors.BuildError: COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat target/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar: file does not exist
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed `custom_context=True,` and the problem went away.

EDIT:

Using your project tree:

```
import docker
client = docker.from_env()

client.images.build(
    path = './project/src/app/target/',
    dockerfile = '../../../Dockerfile/Dockerfile.name',
    tag='image:version',
)
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, I edited the question to include this point.

Comment: Okay, my bad. 
I made a new test with a COPY command in the Dockerfile and it works using `dockerfile` ([path within the build context to the Dockerfile](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/images.html?highlight=build)) along with `path`, I dropped `fileobj`. Let me know if it suits you.

Comment: It works! Moreover, even if the documentation refers to the "path within the build context to the Dockerfile", it works for a Dockerfile outside the build context if an absolute path is specified.

Answer (score 4):

Even if the documentation refers to the *"path* **within** *the build context to the Dockerfile"*, it works for a Dockerfile **outside** the build context if an **absolute path** is specified.

Using my project tree:

```
client.images.build(
    path = '/opt/project/src/',
    dockerfile = '/opt/project/dockerfile/Dockerfile.name',
    tag = 'image:version'
)
```